# Salesforce copy Production to Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I am trying to use the data loader to copy Salesforce backup (scheduled job) to Salesforce Sandbox. Now I know the user Ids would be different and it may result in errors. Hence would it make sense for me to possibly remove all users from the Sandbox, add the users that are currently in Production org to Salesforce Sandbox then use the data loader to insert the accounts and opportunities.

Help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Actually, all user ID's will be the same in production and sandbox, assuming the user was not originally created in the sandbox directly. This means that any data you copy from production will match all user ID values perfectly.

Comment: As @jagular said, a full data sandbox would be the way to go.

Comment: One does not simply copy data to Sandbox. Just pay the money, man...

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to copy data from your production org to sandbox, I would suggest using an app like SFXOrgData (http://www.sfApex.com) to accomplish this. I developed this app specifically for this purpose. It lets you select your Account records, and will automatically detect the associated opportunity records and the copies this records into the sandbox.

For the User records, *sfdcfox* is correct, the record Id's will match between production and sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

If your data model is complex (many levels of objects) and you don't need to refresh the data very frequently, you might find a full sandbox  more convenient than copying the data yourself.  You'll have to contact your Salesforce rep to get one of these.

You can refresh a full sandbox every 30 days.  I believe the IDs for all records will be the same in both systems.